# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected type 'th', but it was: a custom nh object

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

**I tried to handle this asynchronous function by accessing two firebase firestore collection at a time. But the following error happened.** The first updateDoc function flawlessly worked but give for the second one.

```
const handleGiveAccess = async (uid, courseId) => {
        const reqDocRef = doc(db, `users/${uid}/sent_requests/${uid}_${courseId}`);
        updateDoc(reqDocRef, { enrollmentStatus: "resolved" })
          .then(() => {
            toast.success("Added to Resolved List! Refresh to see changes");
            console.log("Document successfully updated!");
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
          });
    
        const requestsDocs = doc(db, `requests/${uid}_${courseId}`);
        updateDoc(requestsDocs, { enrollmentStatus: "resolved" })
          .then(() => {
            console.log("Enrollment status updated in requests collection!");
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
          });
    
        const courseRef = doc(db, "courses", courseId);
        const totalEnrolledRef = collection(courseRef, "enrolled_list");
    
        const data = {
          uid,
        };
    
        setDoc(totalEnrolledRef, data)
          .then(() => {
            console.log("Document successfully written!");
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
          });};
```

Comment: Please include your imports from the top of the file in your code samples. Please also include the code that calls this `handleGiveAccess` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from these lines:

```js
const totalEnrolledRef = collection(courseRef, "enrolled_list");

setDoc(totalEnrolledRef, data)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
  });
```

Here, `totalEnrolledRef` is a `CollectionReference` object. On the following line you attempt to call [`setDoc<T>(reference: DocumentReference<T>, data: WithFieldValue<T>): Promise<void>`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#setdoc) with a `CollectionReference` instead of a `DocumentReference`. You probably intended to call [`addDoc<T>(reference: CollectionReference<T>, data: WithFieldValue<T>): Promise<DocumentReference<T>>`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#adddoc) instead. The error message you got would be referencing the compressed names for these classes used in production.

```js
const totalEnrolledRef = collection(courseRef, "enrolled_list");

addDoc(totalEnrolledRef, data) // <-- corrected here
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
  });
```

**Note:** To prevent this occurring in the future you should avoid calling variables `somethingRef`. You should use `somethingDocRef` (for `DocumentReference` objects) and `somethingColRef` (for `CollectionReference` objects). This would have helped to highlight the issue when you reviewed your code.

**Note:** Your current code has a number of floating promises. You should make sure these are properly handled in your `async` function. You may also consider using a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) (using `doc(totalEnrolledRef)` to generate a new DocumentReference to replace the `addDoc` step above).